# Best practice for storing enums and user defined values

Tags: c#, database

I am in situation where I need to store a payment type enumeration value in the database for record keeping.

The problem is that I would like to add the ability for end user define their own value types.

I understand that I can use a negative range in my enumeration for my own values since user defined types will have an id greater than 0 but would that be a correct approach?

Or maybe I should have a second column like CustomPaymentType and referenced to PaymentType table for a data consistency?

Comment: Not sure if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406550/what-is-the-best-practices-in-database-design-when-i-want-to-store-a-value-that?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an enumeration.

Enumerations are only useful for things that are constant by their nature, like days of the week.

Instead use a reference table in the data base like CustomPaymentType (Id,PaymentTypeName)
then you can use a class that looks like:

```
public class CustomPaymentType
{
    public string paymentTypeName { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    // if you need "Constant payment types usable in code, just add something like:
    public static CustomPaymentType CashPayment
    {
        get { return new CustomPaymentType() { Id = 7, paymentTypeName= "CashPayment" } }
    }

    public static CustomPaymentType CreditPayment
    {
        get { return new CustomPaymentType() { Id = 7,paymentTypeName= "CreditPayment" } }
    }
}
```

This approach is pretty good, because you have both the ease of coding about well known specific instances that you may need while coding, and its also very extendable.

Comment: Not sure that i got this.
Do you propose to have all the types in database?
If yes then i would simply need to generate the predefined types on database creation?

Comment: @NullReference yep... and you can add another payment type without even opening your code, just throw a dll somewhere, and add some configuration to let the program know about the DLL

Comment: Alright.
Do you think that it would be better to use negative ids for predefined methods so there would be no collision with the user defined ones?

Comment: @NullReference i think that it doesn't matter which id you choose to use as long as you give the user an error when he tries to define an id that already exist.

Comment: Basically the negative id would simply help identify the built in payment so for example its name could be localized independently from what name it actually has in the database. Yes of course since the id generation will be done in code and not database side ensuring uniqueness of id is required. Thanks!

Comment: @NullReference Don't use negative numbers to identify something special. Just add an addtional column like `IsBuiltIn` and your code will become more readable / maintainable.